# Is there a non-US app (Chrome/iPhone/Cloud) where one can set financial goals and keep track of progress?

Tags: savings, mexico

I'm looking for an applications where I can set individual financial goals such as a house, a car, vacations, etc, set how much money I need for said goal, and log progress towards it. Ideally this would have a nice visualization of where I stand in each goal with graphs/gauges/bars/etc.

I can't seem to find anything that will do just this.

Answer (score 1):

Mint can probably do this. They probably have apps now and their online service has had charts for years.

Comment: But it only works for US/Canadians.

Comment: Yes, @littleadv, and being based in Mexico, I need something more targeted to a general audience...